# Reading an xml file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have this (below) xml file which I would like to import into pandas using pdx.read_xml(). I tried at first to find the root with this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('DOCDB-202141-Amend-PubDate20211005AndBefore-EP-0002.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

and then use the root like this:

```
df = pdx.read_xml('myfile.xml', [root.tag, "Element '{http://www.epo.org/exchange}exchange-documents' at 0x7fe0f85d6770"])
```

but it does not seem to work (Keyerror). How can I read the xml file?
Unfortunately I cannot provide you with further information as I don't know yet the exact content of the xml file. I only know that it is a dataframe from PATSTAT that should be put in pandas. In case you need more info just let me know.

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2018 rel. 2 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) by  (EPO / Europäisches Patentamt München) -->
<!DOCTYPE exch:exchange-documents SYSTEM "docdb-entities.dtd">
<exch:exchange-documents xmlns:exch="http://www.epo.org/exchange" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.epo.org/exchange exchange-documents-v2.5.8.xsd" date-of-exchange="20211011" dtd-version="2.5.8" file="DOCDB-202141-Amend-PubDate20211005AndBefore-EP-0001" no-of-documents="0000032" originating-office="EP">
    <exch:exchange-document country="EP" doc-number="2224545" kind="C0" doc-id="470936316" date-publ="20170622" family-id="42184427" is-representative="NO" date-of-last-exchange="20211011" date-of-previous-exchange="20210126" date-added-docdb="20170630" originating-office="EP" status="A">
        <exch:bibliographic-data>
            <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb">
                <document-id lang="en">
                    <country>EP</country>
                    <doc-number>2224545</doc-number>
                    <kind>C0</kind>
                    <date>20170622</date>
                </document-id>
            </exch:publication-reference>
            <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc">
                <document-id lang="en">
                    <doc-number>EP2224545</doc-number>
                </document-id>
            </exch:publication-reference>
            <exch:publication-reference data-format="original">
                <document-id>
                    <doc-number>2224545</doc-number>
                </document-id>
            </exch:publication-reference>
            <exch:classifications-ipcr>
                <classification-ipcr sequence="1">
                    <text>H01R  13/514       20060101AFI20151116BHEP        </text>
                </classification-ipcr>
                <classification-ipcr sequence="2">
                    <text>H01R  13/46        20060101ALI20151116BHEP        </text>
                </classification-ipcr>
                <classification-ipcr sequence="3">
                    <text>H01R  13/66        20060101ALI20151116BHEP        </text>
                </classification-ipcr>
                <classification-ipcr sequence="4">
                    <text>H01R  24/58        20110101ALI20110101RMEP        </text>
                </classification-ipcr>
                <classification-ipcr sequence="5">
                    <text>H01R  24/64        20110101ALI20151116BHEP        </text>
                </classification-ipcr>
            </exch:classifications-ipcr>
            <exch:patent-classifications>
                <patent-classification sequence="1">
                    <classification-scheme office="EP" scheme="CPCI">
                        <date>20130101</date>
                    </classification-scheme>
                    <classification-symbol>H01R  13/465       </classification-symbol>
                    <symbol-position>L</symbol-position>
                    <classification-value>A</classification-value>
                    <classification-status>B</classification-status>
                    <classification-data-source>H</classification-data-source>
                    <generating-office>EP</generating-office>
                    <action-date>
                        <date>20130101</date>
                    </action-date>
                </patent-classification>
                <patent-classification sequence="2">
                    <classification-scheme office="EP" scheme="CPCI">
                        <date>20130101</date>
                    </classification-scheme>
                    <classification-symbol>H01R  13/514       </classification-symbol>
                    <symbol-position>F</symbol-position>
                    <classification-value>I</classification-value>
                    <classification-status>B</classification-status>
                    <classification-data-source>H</classification-data-source>
                    <generating-office>EP</generating-office>
                    <action-date>
                        <date>20130101</date>
                    </action-date>
                </patent-classification>
                <patent-classification sequence="3">
                    <classification-scheme office="EP" scheme="CPCI">
                        <date>20130101</date>
                    </classification-scheme>
                    <classification-symbol>H01R  13/6658      </classification-symbol>
                    <symbol-position>L</symbol-position>
                    <classification-value>I</classification-value>
                    <classification-status>B</classification-status>
                    <classification-data-source>H</classification-data-source>
                    <generating-office>EP</generating-office>
                    <action-date>
                        <date>20130101</date>
                    </action-date>
                </patent-classification>
                <patent-classification sequence="4">
                    <classification-scheme office="EP" scheme="CPCI">
                        <date>20130101</date>
                    </classification-scheme>
                    <classification-symbol>H01R  24/64        </classification-symbol>
                    <symbol-position>L</symbol-position>
                    <classification-value>A</classification-value>
                    <classification-status>B</classification-status>
                    <classification-data-source>H</classification-data-source>
                    <generating-office>EP</generating-office>
                    <action-date>
                        <date>20130819</date>
                    </action-date>
                </patent-classification>
            </exch:patent-classifications>
            <exch:application-reference is-representative="NO" doc-id="274384603" data-format="docdb">
                <document-id>
                    <country>EP</country>
                    <doc-number>10152335</doc-number>
                    <kind>A</kind>
                    <date>20100201</date>
                </document-id>
            </exch:application-reference>
            <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                <document-id>
                    <doc-number>EP20100152335</doc-number>
                </document-id>
            </exch:application-reference>
            <exch:application-reference data-format="original">
                <document-id>
                    <doc-number>10152335.5</doc-number>
                </document-id>
            </exch:application-reference>
            <exch:language-of-publication>en</exch:language-of-publication>
            <exch:priority-claims>
                <exch:priority-claim sequence="1" data-format="docdb">
                    <document-id doc-id="322475065">
                        <country>US</country>
                        <doc-number>39481609</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                        <date>20090227</date>
                    </document-id>
                    <exch:priority-active-indicator>Y</exch:priority-active-indicator>
                </exch:priority-claim>
                <exch:priority-claim sequence="1" data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>US20090394816</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:priority-claim>
                <exch:priority-claim sequence="1" data-format="original">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>394816</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:priority-claim>
            </exch:priority-claims>
            <exch:parties>
                <exch:applicants>
                    <exch:applicant sequence="1" data-format="docdb">
                        <exch:applicant-name>
                            <name>TYCO ELECTRONICS CORP</name>
                        </exch:applicant-name>
                        <residence>
                            <country>US</country>
                        </residence>
                    </exch:applicant>
                    <exch:applicant sequence="1" data-format="docdba">
                        <exch:applicant-name>
                            <name>Tyco Electronics Corporation</name>
                        </exch:applicant-name>
                    </exch:applicant>
                </exch:applicants>
                <exch:inventors>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="1" data-format="docdb">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>PEPE PAUL JOHN</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                        <residence>
                            <country>US</country>
                        </residence>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="2" data-format="docdb">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>MUIR SHELDON EASTON</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                        <residence>
                            <country>US</country>
                        </residence>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="1" data-format="docdba">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>Pepe, Paul John</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="2" data-format="docdba">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>Muir, Sheldon Easton</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                    </exch:inventor>
                </exch:inventors>
            </exch:parties>
            <exch:designation-of-states>
                <exch:designation-epc>
                    <exch:contracting-states>
                        <country>AT</country>
                        <country>BE</country>
                        <country>BG</country>
                        <country>CH</country>
                        <country>CY</country>
                        <country>CZ</country>
                        <country>DE</country>
                        <country>DK</country>
                        <country>EE</country>
                        <country>ES</country>
                        <country>FI</country>
                        <country>FR</country>
                        <country>GB</country>
                        <country>GR</country>
                        <country>HR</country>
                        <country>HU</country>
                        <country>IE</country>
                        <country>IS</country>
                        <country>IT</country>
                        <country>LI</country>
                        <country>LT</country>
                        <country>LU</country>
                        <country>LV</country>
                        <country>MC</country>
                        <country>MK</country>
                        <country>MT</country>
                        <country>NL</country>
                        <country>NO</country>
                        <country>PL</country>
                        <country>PT</country>
                        <country>RO</country>
                        <country>SE</country>
                        <country>SI</country>
                        <country>SK</country>
                        <country>SM</country>
                        <country>TR</country>
                    </exch:contracting-states>
                    <exch:up-participating-states>
                        <country>IT</country>
                    </exch:up-participating-states>
                    <exch:validation-states>
                        <country>new</country>
                    </exch:validation-states>
                </exch:designation-epc>
            </exch:designation-of-states>
            <exch:invention-title lang="de" data-format="docdba">Kassette fÃ¼r ein Kabelverbindungssystem</exch:invention-title>
            <exch:invention-title lang="en" data-format="docdba">Cassette for a cable interconnect system</exch:invention-title>
            <exch:invention-title lang="fr" data-format="docdba">Cassette pour systÃ¨me d&apos;interconnexion de cÃ¢bles</exch:invention-title>
            <exch:dates-of-public-availability>
                <exch:printed-with-grant>
                    <document-id>
                        <date>20170622</date>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:printed-with-grant>
            </exch:dates-of-public-availability>
        </exch:bibliographic-data>
        <exch:patent-family>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="NO">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>10152335</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP20100152335</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>2224545</doc-number>
                        <kind>A1</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP2224545</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>2224545</doc-number>
                        <kind>B1</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP2224545</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="3">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>2224545</doc-number>
                        <kind>C0</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="3">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP2224545</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="NO">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>JP</country>
                        <doc-number>2010028634</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>JP20100028634</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>JP</country>
                        <doc-number>2010205724</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>JP2010205724</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="NO">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>TW</country>
                        <doc-number>99102542</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>TW20100102542</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>TW</country>
                        <doc-number>I497834</doc-number>
                        <kind>B</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>TWI497834B</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>TW</country>
                        <doc-number>201037898</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>TW201037898</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="YES">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>US</country>
                        <doc-number>39481609</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>US20090394816</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>US</country>
                        <doc-number>7909643</doc-number>
                        <kind>B2</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>US7909643</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>US</country>
                        <doc-number>2010221931</doc-number>
                        <kind>A1</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>US2010221931</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:abstract lang="en" country="EP" doc-number="2224545" kind="A1" data-format="docdba" abstract-source="EPO">
                <exch:p>A cassette (20) includes a housing (30) having a front (34) and a rear (36). The housing (30) has a plurality of plug cavities (42) open at the front (34) for receiving plugs therein, and the housing (30) has a rear chamber (102) open to the plug cavities. The cassette also includes a contact subassembly (100) having a circuit board (104) and a plurality of contacts (144) arranged in contact sets (146) coupled to the circuit board (104). Each contact set (146) is configured to mate with a corresponding plug, where the contact subassembly (100) is loaded into the rear chamber (102) such that the contact sets are received in different corresponding plug cavities (42). The circuit board (104) is oriented generally parallel to the front of the housing (30) when the contact subassembly (100) is loaded into the rear chamber (102).</exch:p>
            </exch:abstract>
        </exch:patent-family>
    </exch:exchange-document>
    <exch:exchange-document country="EP" doc-number="2228299" kind="C0" doc-id="470936320" date-publ="20170622" family-id="42229294" is-representative="NO" date-of-last-exchange="20211011" date-of-previous-exchange="20210126" date-added-docdb="20170630" originating-office="EP" status="A">
        <exch:bibliographic-data>
            <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb">
                <document-id lang="de">
                    <country>EP</country>
                    <doc-number>2228299</doc-number>
                    <kind>C0</kind>
                    <date>20170622</date>
                </document-id>
            </exch:publication-reference>
            <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc">
...
                </exch:applicants>
                <exch:inventors>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="1" data-format="docdb">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>SCHINDLER RODNEY A</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                        <residence>
                            <country>US</country>
                        </residence>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="2" data-format="docdb">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>SHEIDLER ALAN D</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                        <residence>
                            <country>US</country>
                        </residence>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="3" data-format="docdb">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>SCHMITZ JOSEPH P</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                        <residence>
                            <country>US</country>
                        </residence>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="1" data-format="docdba">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>Schindler, Rodney A.</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="2" data-format="docdba">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>Sheidler, Alan D.</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                    </exch:inventor>
                    <exch:inventor sequence="3" data-format="docdba">
                        <exch:inventor-name>
                            <name>Schmitz, Joseph P.</name>
                        </exch:inventor-name>
                    </exch:inventor>
                </exch:inventors>
            </exch:parties>
            <exch:designation-of-states>
                <exch:designation-epc>
                    <exch:contracting-states>
                        <country>AT</country>
                        <country>BE</country>
                        <country>BG</country>
                        <country>CH</country>
                        <country>CY</country>
                        <country>CZ</country>
                        <country>DE</country>
                        <country>DK</country>
                        <country>EE</country>
                        <country>ES</country>
                        <country>FI</country>
                        <country>FR</country>
                        <country>GB</country>
                        <country>GR</country>
                        <country>HR</country>
                        <country>HU</country>
                        <country>IE</country>
                        <country>IS</country>
                        <country>IT</country>
                        <country>LI</country>
                        <country>LT</country>
                        <country>LU</country>
                        <country>LV</country>
                        <country>MC</country>
                        <country>MK</country>
                        <country>MT</country>
                        <country>NL</country>
                        <country>NO</country>
                        <country>PL</country>
                        <country>PT</country>
                        <country>RO</country>
                        <country>SE</country>
                        <country>SI</country>
                        <country>SK</country>
                        <country>SM</country>
                        <country>TR</country>
                    </exch:contracting-states>
                    <exch:up-participating-states>
                        <country>NL</country>
                    </exch:up-participating-states>
                    <exch:validation-states>
                        <country>PL</country>
                    </exch:validation-states>
                </exch:designation-epc>
            </exch:designation-of-states>
            <exch:invention-title lang="de" data-format="docdba">Motor f&#252;r eine landwirtschaftliche Erntemaschine mit isochroner Drehmomentkurve mit &#220;berleistung</exch:invention-title>
            <exch:invention-title lang="en" data-format="docdba">Engine for an agricultural harvester having isochronous torque curve with power bulge</exch:invention-title>
            <exch:invention-title lang="fr" data-format="docdba">Moteur pour moissonneuse agricole dot&#233; d&apos;une courbe de couple isochrone avec gonflement d&apos;alimentation</exch:invention-title>
            <exch:dates-of-public-availability>
                <exch:printed-with-grant>
                    <document-id>
                        <date>20170622</date>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:printed-with-grant>
            </exch:dates-of-public-availability>
        </exch:bibliographic-data>
        <exch:patent-family>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="NO">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>AU</country>
                        <doc-number>2010201937</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>AU20100201937</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>AU</country>
                        <doc-number>2010201937</doc-number>
                        <kind>A1</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>AU2010201937</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="NO">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>BR</country>
                        <doc-number>PI1001711</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>BR2010PI01711</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>BR</country>
                        <doc-number>PI1001711</doc-number>
                        <kind>A2</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>BRPI1001711</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="NO">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EA</country>
                        <doc-number>201000681</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EA20100000681</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EA</country>
                        <doc-number>201000681</doc-number>
                        <kind>A1</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EA201000681</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="NO">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>10161600</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP20100161600</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>2253822</doc-number>
                        <kind>A2</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP2253822</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>2253822</doc-number>
                        <kind>A3</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP2253822</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="3">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>2253822</doc-number>
                        <kind>B1</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="3">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP2253822</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="4">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>EP</country>
                        <doc-number>2253822</doc-number>
                        <kind>C0</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="4">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>EP2253822</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:family-member>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="docdb" is-representative="YES">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>US</country>
                        <doc-number>47019809</doc-number>
                        <kind>A</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:application-reference data-format="epodoc">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>US20090470198</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:application-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>US</country>
                        <doc-number>8352155</doc-number>
                        <kind>B2</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="1">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>US8352155</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="docdb" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <country>US</country>
                        <doc-number>2010299048</doc-number>
                        <kind>A1</kind>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
                <exch:publication-reference data-format="epodoc" sequence="2">
                    <document-id>
                        <doc-number>US2010299048</doc-number>
                    </document-id>
                </exch:publication-reference>
            </exch:family-member>
            <exch:abstract lang="en" country="EP" doc-number="2253822" kind="A2" data-format="docdba" abstract-source="EPO">
                <exch:p>A method of operating an internal combustion engine (12) in an agricultural harvester (10) includes the steps of operating the engine (12) in a normal mode with a base torque curve (42) as a function of engine operating speed and engine power output, the base torque curve (42) being generally isochronous at a rated operating speed over a power output range terminating at a rated power output; and operating the engine (12) in a boost mode with a boost torque curve (48) when a power boost is required above the rated power output, the boost torque curve (48) having a power output which is above the base torque curve over a predefined range of the operating speed.</exch:p>
            </exch:abstract>
        </exch:patent-family>
    </exch:exchange-document>
</exch:exchange-documents>
```

EDITED:
The above xml is incomplete due to space limitts.
You can acces the full xml from here: [enter link description here](https://publication.epo.org/raw-data/product?productId=111)
The expected pandas dataframe should have the following as columns:

Country, date-produced, date-of-exchange,dtd-version,file, no-of-document, originating-office, status

Comment: you want the read process pandas in particular?

Comment: Yes, I have to convert it into a pandas data frame because my team works on it...

Comment: could you create a picture or data frame expected because some requirements is attribute and "date-produced" does not appear in xml file

Answer (score 1):

you could read an xml file

after read xml by

```
from pandas import read_xml as pdx
xml_data = open(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\stackoverflow\file.xml', 'r').read()
```

you want to specify the path you want to follow like

```
df = pdx(xml_data,

             xpath="//exch:family-member//exch:application-reference//document-id",

             namespaces={"exch": "http://www.epo.org/exchange"})
```

the output is with columns ['country', 'doc-number', 'kind']

Comment: actually if I try this approach the result is a df with 0 {'@xmlns:exch': 'http://www.epo.org/exchange',... as row and exch:exchange-documents as single column

Comment: I edited the comment and tried it with part of your xml and it returns a dataframe with country and doc-number and kind, changing xpath gives you different output

Comment: I could not try it on whole your xml because I copy it and it is invalid

Comment: actually it is a part of the entire xml since stackoverflow does not allow me to put it all. If there is a way please tell me and I will be happy to share it all.

Comment: Actually, an issue might be that I am using this import pandas_read_xml as pdx rather than pandas as I get the following error (though I updated pandas): module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_xml'. My version is 1.1.3 though I updated it in jupyter with pip install --upgrade pandas --user

Comment: you need to do "from pandas import read_xml as pdx"

Comment: ok but if I do that then I get: "read_xml() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xpath'"

Comment: I edited the code in my answer

Comment: It says: cannot import name 'read_xml' from 'pandas' (/Users/federiconutarelli/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py)

Comment: To be fully clear I did: !pip install pandas==1.4.3 which was installed sucessfully and then print(pd.__version__) which is 1.1.3 (strange!)

Comment: could you install 1.3.4 and try it again

Comment: done. Same error actually...

Comment: Ok I did uninstall and reinstall panda and now it works. Still not clear why I get 3 columns on the pandass dataframe though...

Comment: because xpath i specify for part of your xml you could change it or could you give an expected output

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should remove square brackets from read expression.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).